# Exception in native call from js ?? react-native-firebase/database error

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

[image]

```
react-native-firebase/app << set complete and call OK

import Firebase from "@react-native-firebase/app"
import Database from "@react-native/firebase/database <<<error start,,,,


    Database().ref("users/"+ "userId").set({
     hopoint:5,
     userPoint:5000
    })
<<<<< error on.

just call Database() <<< error On
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use google services 4.3.5 like so `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5` its listed on firebase project config, used to be 4.3.4, so maybe minor fixes in 4.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Based on these lines:

```
Database().ref("users/" + "userId").set({
  hopoint:5,
  userPoint:5000
})
```

You have logged in as user `@XYZ`, but you are getting a permissions error because you are trying to write to `@userId`'s data.

You probably meant to use the **value** of `userId` and not the string `"userId"`.

```
Database().ref("users/" + userId).set({
  hopoint:5,
  userPoint:5000
})
```